# Adding more events like Control.Click and Handler.Point for single variable in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers-2

I have two points which are marked dynamically on the map and when I mark the start point it is returning lon,lat, but I want to assign this coordinates to the variable that marked/handled the start symbol and a point.
Ex:

```
measureControls={
              start: new OpenLayers.Control.DrawFeature(start, OpenLayers.Handler.Point),
              stop: new OpenLayers.Control.DrawFeature(stop, OpenLayers.Handler.Point),
```

for the same start and stop, I would like to add event 'click' and assign the point when clicked.

Comment: Please clarify more your question. I could not understand what you want. Your sample could looks like truncated.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are talking about click event feature `enter code here`

```
    function onFeatureSelect(evt) {
            
                          }
        
        
        var selectCtrl = new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature(yourlayername,
            {
            clickout: true, onSelect:onFeatureSelect }
                              );
        
        map.addControl(selectCtrl);
        selectCtrl.activate();
```